# How to know if my ArrayList of objects contains a key String?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a Arraylist of pens, each pen have a colour, a name and a code. I want to know if in my arraylist of pens i will a have or not a pen with the KeyCode "ABCD1". How can i test it?

I tried to use contains in my list of pens passing the code, but know do i acess only the variable not the entire object?

pens.contains(KeyCode)

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to use contains, but i guess i need to acess only the variable for each object not the object

Comment: `contains` method of `List` matches elements not the field values of these elements, so it should be used when you want to check if a specific `Pen` object exists

Comment: Yeah, thats what i mean Ahmed. I need to check only the code for each pen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using java 8+, then you can try something like this

```
boolean b = pens.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.getCode().contains("ABCD1"));
```